# Why it evaluates to string?

Tags: scala

I have following expression:

```
1 + "c"
```

as the result I've got

```
1c
```

I guess, because the compiler convert the expression to:

```
1.toString + "c"
```

For me it is not logic at all, I expect an exception, because the first argument of the expression is an `Int`, it determines the result type.

If it would be reverse like

```
"c" + 1
```

Then I agreed, that the value should be a String.

Why does the compiler not throw an exception on the first expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `scala.Int` has member method [+(x: String): String](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html#+(x:String):String)

`1 + "c"` is just a syntax sugar of  `1.+("c")`, which is calling `+` member method of `1` with argument `"c"`.

From: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation

> Scala has a special punctuation-free syntax for invoking methods that 
>   take one argument. Many Scala programmers use this notation for symbolic-named methods

Comment: And even it *didn't* have that method, then [the implicit conversion to `any2stringadd`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$@any2stringadd[A]extendsAnyVal) would take effect.

Answer (score 1):

As ymonad wrote, conversion is done by + operator in scala.Int.
Please keep also in mind that such convention is compatible with java where you could write:

```
String 1c = 1 + "c";
```